# Android Unable to upload image to server. Wrong image type

Tags: php, android, file-upload, content-type, multipartentity

I have an app that sends an image to a server using HttpCliend and MultipartEntityBuilder. My problem is that the sending isn't successful. I get a message "Invalid file" from the server.

This is my sending method:

```
public void executeMultipartPost() throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException {
    String result = "";
    Log.d("DrawingFragment", "executeMultipartPost");

    httpClient.setCookieStore(signiture.getCookies());

    HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(url);

    File file = new File(signiturePath);

    FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
    Log.v("FileBody", bin.getFilename());
    Log.d("signiturePath", signiturePath);
    MultipartEntityBuilder multiPartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder
            .create();

    Log.i("HttpRequest Headers", "===========================================================");
    Header headers[] = httpPostRequest.getAllHeaders();
    for(Header h:headers) {
        Log.i("", h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue() + "\n");
    }
    Log.i("", "===========================================================");
    multiPartEntityBuilder.addTextBody("Content-Type", "image/png");

    multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart("file", bin);

    httpPostRequest.setEntity(multiPartEntityBuilder.build());

    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPostRequest);

    Log.i("HttpResponse Headers", "===========================================================");
    headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();
    for(Header h:headers) {
        Log.i("", h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue() + "\n");
    }
    Log.i("", "===========================================================");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

    if (inputStream != null) {
        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
    } else {
        result = "Did not work!";
    }

    Log.i("UploadPhoto", result);
}
```

And this is the php server:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "\n"; 
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "\n"; 

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    echo "Passed First If";
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "./" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

And this is what I have in the logcat:

```
07-14 22:57:05.720: I/HttpRequest Headers(14081): ===========================================================
07-14 22:57:05.720: I/(14081): ===========================================================
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/HttpResponse Headers(14081): ===========================================================
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/(14081): Date: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 20:59:38 GMT
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/(14081): Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/(14081): X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/(14081): X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/(14081): Content-type: text/html
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/(14081): Content-Length: 63
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/(14081): ===========================================================
07-14 22:57:05.960: I/UploadPhoto(14081): Upload: image.pngUpload: application/octet-streamInvalid file
```

As you can see the file get's to the server but does not pass any of the if conditions. I tried with `httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "image/png;");` but it didn't work. Can you tell me what is the problem and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I upload the image as a binary body and there I set the type and the name:

```
multiPartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(imageName, byteArray, ContentType.create("image/png"), "image.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
FileBody bin = new FileBody(file, "image/png");
```

You want to set the content type for the file, not for the request.
See the [`org.apache.http` documentation for more details](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html)

Comment: Using like that FileBody is deprecated.

Comment: You mean using a string as the second argument? The recommended way seems to be `new FileBody(file, new ContentType("image/png"));` then.

Comment: The constructor ContentType(String) is undefined. I tried the other way with new FileBody(file, "image/png"); but then the file does not even gets to the server.

Comment: Look at the documentation. String to ContentType would be `ContentType.create("image/png");` as it seems.

Comment: Yeah.. I tried but the result is the same. This way the file does not even get to the server. The first two echos doesn't print anything..

Comment: Then did you remove addTextBody()?